# Regex pattern to match any substring longer than two characters from a provided string

Tags: regex, string, visual-studio-2015

I have an input string, let's say `potato`.  I have a large project in Visual Studio.  I'm trying to write a regex to find any substring of the input longer than two characters.  For example, `pot`, `ato`, `tat`, etc.

`/([p,o,t,a]){2,10}/g`

This finds any string between two and 10 characters long containing those letters, but pays no regard to the order.  I'm looking to effectively do

`/([potato]){2,10}/g`

and have it return just the substrings that are found in the provided string.  Is this even possible?

Comment: First of all if you are searching for substring then maximum length should be length of that string. In this case 6.

Comment: Maybe through recursion e.g. if it maches with s[i], then call with s[i+1]?

Comment: What's source of input ? User ? And where does it look for substring of user entered string ?

Comment: @noob, good catch.  My actual input string is 10 characters and I just forgot to update it for the question.  The source of the input is user.  This is me typing into the search box in Visual Studio

Comment: @DavidBrossard seeing as how I'm just using the search box in visual studio, I don't know how I could recurse

Comment: Not really possible in regex alone. Additionally, no need to repeat yourself in square brackts: `/([pota]){2,10}/g` is effectively the same.

Comment: Okay, that's kinda what I expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the given example this regex would do the job:

```
(((pota?|ota)t?|tat)o?|ato)
```

This takes all possible 3-character sub-strings in a nested OR (`|`) expression, and matches all subsequent characters of 'potato' if they are present (optional).

There is a repeatable logic in this expression so that it could be built dynamically from any user-provided search item.

To demonstrate this, here is a live JavaScript snippet that does just that. It lets you enter a search string and the text to be searched. Then it outputs the regular expression and applies it, highlighting the matched text parts.

It will be straightforward to translate this to any other language that supports regular expressions:

```js
// Core function
function buildRegexFor(find) {
    var regexStr = find.substr(0,3);
    for (var i = 1; i < find.length - 2; i++) {
        regexStr = '(' + regexStr + find.substr(i+2,1) + '?|' + find.substr(i,3) + ')';
    }
    return regexStr;
}

// Handle button click event 
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
    // (1) read input
    var find = document.querySelector('input').value;
    var str = document.querySelector('textarea').value;

    // (2) build regular expression using above function
    var regexStr = buildRegexFor(find);
    
    // (3) apply regular expression to text and highlight all found instances   
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(regexStr, 'g'), "<b>$1</b>");
    
    // (4) output
    document.querySelector('span').textContent = regexStr;
    document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = str;
};
```

```css
b { background: yellow }
```

```html
Value to find:<br>
<input value="potato"><br>
<button>find</button><br>
Text to find in:<br>
<textarea cols=40>There is a spot in the botanic garden 
on this atol that beats all stats as it rotates potatoes.</textarea><br>
Regex: <span></span><br>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you leave a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You could programmatically generate the string (example in Python):

```
s = "potato"
min_length = 3

substrings = set()
for x in range(len(s)):
    for y in range(x + min_length, len(s)):
        substrings.add(s[x:y])

pattern = "(" + "|".join(substrings) + ")"
print(pattern)
```